# Неправильный путь ссылок и картинок в joomla 2.5.17

Tags: joomla, html, css, php

Собственно вопрос вот в чём, закидываю в редактор html код, создаю модуль, а там не отображается картинка. Путь который задаёт джумла `CMS/joomla_2.5/img/logo.png`, а надо `CMS\Joomla_2.5\templates\euro\img\logo.png`. euro это название шаблона по умолчанию, подскажите в чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в корявости некоторых шаблонов и джумлы вообще. Столкнулся с подобной проблемой (фото в слайдер вставлялось с добавочно прописанным путем '/templates/vicam/').
У Вас есть два решения:

1) Загружать нужные вам для отображения картинки в корневую папку битрикса (а не шаблона).
2) Искать файлы, в которых прописываются пути до изображений и править их вручную (в этом случае после манипуляций лучше не обновлять джумлу, т.к. файлы могут перезаписаться великой джумлой). конструкции будут/были такого типа

```
<img src="'.$this->baseurl.'/templates/vicam/'.$img2.'" alt="'. $pictures->{"image_intro_alt"}.'" />
```

Вот собсно и сам код, который пришлось выдирать и ручками удалять '/templates/vicam/'